# How to split in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

Is there any way to split and then join a string in a textbox?

Example:

I had a textbox named Textbox1 that has a value of `"001-2012-0116"` then I want to split it by this ("-") and then join the resulting 3 strings

Then the  result will become `"00120120116"`

then  I want to get the result and put it in a `resultNumber` whose datatype is string.

**To summarize it :**

```
Textbox1(Value) = "001-2012-0116"

Dim resultNumber as String

resultNumber(Value) = "00120120116"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others suggest, split isn't the best way to go in this case. You'll need to use `String.Join()` after splitting to get that expected result :

```
Dim resultNumber = String.Join("", "001-2012-0116".Split("-"))
```

So it is kind of double work. Will be more concise to simply replace dash (`-`) with empty string :

```
Dim resultNumber = "001-2012-0116".Replace("-", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `String.Replace()` in this situation:

```
resultNumber = Textbox1.Value.ToString().Replace("-", String.Empty)
```

Obviously this keeps everything as a `String`, but if you want to use the string as numeric (as they are numeric) then you would need to convert it to an `Integer`.

If you want to split the value into an array of strings then you can use the following, but you're not really wanting this result, but you asked about splitting strings...

```
Dim result As String() = words.Split("-")
```

Comment: Thank you guys... It gives me a lot of trouble but it seem for all of you its like nothing.. Thanks again ^_^

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach as inspiration:

```
Sub Main
Dim txt as String
Dim intVal as Int64
txt =  "001-2012-0116"

If(Int64.TryParse(txt.Replace("-",""), intVal))
Console.WriteLine(intVal)
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been answered, but sometimes I prefer to use the `RegularExpression` Class.

In your case this is how it can be accomplished...

```
 Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions 'Need to import the namespace

 Dim resultNumber As String =  Regex.Replace(TextBox1.Text, "-", String.Empty) 'Do a simple replace on "-"
```

On the other hand your doing a simple replace on a single string, so the answer that you accepted would be more suitable in this case. Regular expressions in my opinion are great when dealing with patterns and such.